# How to get hasOne property inside view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I echo category name when in Urls view? I get this error:

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.url_id' in 'where clause'
 (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`url_id` = 23 and `categories`.`url_id` is not null limit 1
```

I believe the query should be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categories.id = 1
```

**Urls table**

```
id | url | category_id
1    www.asdf.com   1
```

**Categories table**

```
id | category 
1    Something
```

Migration for adding column Category_id to Urls table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('urls', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('urls');
    });
}
```

(hm I believe I need to fix this and put `references('id')->on('categories')` )

**Url model**

```
class Url extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'urls';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category');
    }

}
```

**Url index controller**

```
$urls = URL::paginate(100)
return view('urls.index')->with('urls', $urls);
```

**Urls.index view**

```
{{ $url->category->category }}
```

---

If I change **Url model** to this

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

and when I do `var_dump($url->category)`, the correct SQL query is generated:

```
select * from `categories` where `categories`.`id` = '1' limit 1
```

but I still can't get column name with `{{ $url->category->category }}`

because error is `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `belongsTo()` relationship instead of `hasOne()`:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Comment: I did as I wrote, but I have found out what the problem was - for some urls in category_id I had NULL value. This works 
            @if($url->category_id)
            {{ $url->category->category }}
            @endif